# Footer display problem in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser, footer

It is bit weird scenario to explain it in words. The footer of site I'm working on looks good on most of the browsers except IE7. Below are the screenshots will give you the idea.

[IE8/FF/Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgWN2.jpg)

[IE7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxRmr.jpg) (moved half screen right)

The footer has following CSS. When I remove the CSS it displays fine.

```
#footer-holder
{
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    *border: none;
    z-index: 10000;
    height: 30px;
    /* For WebKit */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(255,255,255,0.1)), to(rgba(0,100,255,0.70)));
    /* For Mozilla */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.1), rgba(0,100,255,0.70));
    /* For lt IE8 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr=#01FFFFFF, EndColorStr=#A50064FF);
    /* For gt IE8 */
    background: -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr=#01FFFFFF, EndColorStr=#A50064FF)";
}
```

I am tired to making it compatible with IE7. Any idea what might be causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue. I had to mention `left: 0px;`. And now it is looking great on IE7. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your html..

Answer (score 0):

Remove the * next to `*border: none;`

Comment: can you post a link to the page?

Comment: I am working on localhost. The web product is yet to be launched. Sorry that I could not provide you the link. But the issue has been resolved. I have posted the answer. :) Thanks